# Dygraphs - leave gaps for missing data?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I'm using Dygraphs to display data. 
Specifically - Dygraph.Gvizchart.
I've tried using connectSeparatedPoint option with no results.
Here is the format I have it in:

```
          [new Date(2012, 5, 13), 0.9880,undefined,null ] ,

          [new Date(2012, 5, 14), 0.9911,undefined,null ] ,

          [new Date(2012, 5, 15), 0.9901,undefined,null ] ,

          [new Date(2012, 5, 16), 0.9920,undefined,null ] ,

          [new Date(2012, 5, 17), 0.9923,undefined,null ] ,

          [new Date(2012, 5, 18), 0.9926,undefined,null ] ,
```

However, when I have a missing date I want the graph to leave a gap until the next data point, not draw a vertical line downwards like it does now. I've tried using 'null', 'undefined', and simply leaving that date out, but to no avail. This vertical line behavior can be deceiving. Any Dygraph gurus know the solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost certainly hitting a bug that was recently [fixed](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/pull/155). Pull in the latest version of dygraphs and give it another try.